# Basics of working with Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How do you:
1. Initialize (create) an Array.
2. Push a String value into it.
3. Push another String value into it.
4. Dump it to get its contents.

Comment: This pretty much sounds like homework. In the future you should be tagging as such :) Else answers like "Use ArrayList", "Use Stack", etc would be after all utterly pointless.

Comment: Not a homework. I apologize if the question seems inappropriate.

Comment: if it isn't homework then you should use the Collections classes, List, Set, Map, etc. Direct use of Array is a code smell 99.99999% of the time.

Comment: I'm new to Java. My background is in ActionScript. In ActionScript these types of objects you mention don't exist. Arrays do.

Comment: OK, nevermind then. I suspected homework because the tutorial is pretty easy to [find](http://google.com/search?q=array+tutorial+site:sun.com) at sun.com and the average student doesn't research at all ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays in Java are a fixed size, determined when you create them.  As such, they have no push methods.

It sounds like you want a [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead, most likely an [`ArrayList<String>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  Lists have an [`add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) function for adding new elements.

The [Java Collections trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) has more information about the various types of collections (List, Set, and Map).

Lists and Sets work with Java's for each operator:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
//List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();

myList.add("One");
myList.add("Two");

// Because we're using a Generic collection, the compiler
// inserts a cast on the next line for you
for (String current : myList) {
    // This section happens once for each elements in myList
    System.out.println(current);
}
// should print "One" and "Two" (without quotes) on separate lines
```

Comment: I finally got around to adding an example.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for answering the question I should have asked!

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] a;
a = new int[5];

a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;
a[3]=4;
a[4]=5;

for(int i =0; i<5; i++)
   System.out.println(a[i]);
```

Java.sun has a good link for array help: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html
This is basically a fixed size array.  If you are looking to push elements in (you do not know the size) you'll want to look at an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Basically an array is a way to hold more than one value at a time. It's like a list of items.In java, initialise an array can be done by using new keyword for example,

```
int arrayName = new int[10];
```

Assigning values to arrays:

```
arrayName[0] = 10;
```

also,

```
int[]ArrList = {1, 2, 3, 4,5};
```

Simple example for int array java are as follows,

```
public class array_ex {

   public static void main(String []args) {

        int arrex[] = {10,20,30}; //Declaring and initializing an array of three elements

        for (int i=0;i&lt;arrex.length;i++){

            System.out.println(arrex[i]);

        }

    }     
}
```

this is also an another example for declaring array,

```
public class array_ex {

   public static void main(String []args) {

        int arrex[] = new int[3]; //declaring array of three items

        arrex[0] =10;

        arrex[1] =20;

        arrex[2] =30;

        //Printing array

        for (int i=0;i&lt;arrex.length;i++){

            System.out.println(arrex[i]);

        }

    }     

}
```

example for pushing s string value

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
String s1 ="sub1";
String s2 ="sub2";
String s3 ="sub3";
ar.add(s1);
ar.add(s2);
ar.add(s3);
String s4 ="sub4";
ar.add(s4);
```

hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
 anArray = new string[10];
 anArray[0] = "MYSTRING";
 string MyString = anArray[0];

for (int i =0; i <10; i++)
{
   System.out.println(anArray[i]);  
}
```

Pretty straightforward as far as arrays go, there are a couple of other libraries in java that can help ease the burdens of using raw arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [Stack](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)?

```
final Stack<String> strings = new Stack<String>();
strings.push("First");
strings.push("Second");
System.out.println(strings.toString());
```

You could also use a [List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or a [Queue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) depending on your needs.

Comment: I wasn't aware that toString on a collection would work, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, it prints a nice little list calling `.toString()` on each element in turn. :D

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like you want a list, but in case you really did mean an array...

```
//1. 
String [] arr = new String[2];
//2.
arr[0] = "first";
//3.
arr[1] = "second";
//4.
for (String s: arr)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```